# Здравствуйте! Есть проблема с ООП в PHP

Tags: php, html, css, ооп, mysqli

Начал недавно изучать ООП и решил переписать с нуля свой скрипт написанный с помощью процедурного стиля в ООП стиль. Но мой код почему-то работает только наполовину.
Смысл скрипта таков - я беру у пользователя .sql файл, удаляю старую таблицу из бд, записываю новую таблицу с помощью mysqli_multi_query(); (sql-файл) Так вот, после того как я нажимаю кнопку отправки файла - форма пропадает, изменений в бд никаких не вносится, а файл оказывается загруженным в указанную мной в скрипте директорию. Как я понял единственное что работает в моём самописном классе - это получение директории конструктором и дальнейшая загрузка файла в неё. Еще я сделал 2 публичных переменных для вывода этапов выполнения скрипта, но они не отображаются при отправке формы => работа скрипта заканчивается на строчке (возможно)

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $this->uploadfile)) {
```

Не знаю что делать, буду благодарен если поможете. Далее скидываю сами скрипты 
(Ошибок никаких не выводится)

1. HTML, CSS форма.

```html
<?php 
session_start(); 
include_once("dbconnect.php");
include_once("sqlclass.php");
echo $form->result1;
echo $form->result2;
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>adminpanel</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div style="margin:0 auto; width:800px; height:630px; border:2px solid gray; padding: 10px 10px; background-color:indigo;">
  <div style="margin:0 auto; width:800px; height:630px; border:2px solid gray; padding: 10px 10px; background-color:white; overflow-y:scroll;">
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="<?php $form->uploadsql(); ?>">
    <!-- Поле MAX_FILE_SIZE должно быть указано до поля загрузки файла -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />
    <!-- Название элемента input определяет имя в массиве $_FILES -->
    Отправить этот файл .sql: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить файл" name="sendsql"/>
</form><br>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

2. Скрипт подключения к базе данных (dbconnect.php)

```html
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "spec_db");
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Ошибка подключения (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}else{
 echo "Успешное подключение к базе данных";
}
```

3. Скрипт-обработчик (Проблемный) (sqlclass.php)

```html
<?php
// working with sql files
class wwsqlf{

public $result1;
public $result2;
protected $upploaddir;
protected $uploadfile;
 function __construct() {
         $dir = $this->upploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/sqlfiles/";
         $this->uploadfile =  $dir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    }
function uploadsql(){
//Если файл был загружен на сервер => удаляем текущую таблицу и ставим новую
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $this->uploadfile)) {
 //удаление таблицы
 $result = $mysqli->query("DROP TABLE results");
if ($result) {
    $this->result1="Удаление текущей таблицы... Успешно!";

    /* очищаем результирующий набор */
    $result->close();
}else{
 $this->result1="Удаление текущей таблицы... Ошибка!";
 $result->close();
 exit();
}
// ставим новую таблицу
$getsql = file_get_contents($this->uploadfile);
$spec1 = $mysqli->mysqli_multi_query($getsql);
if (!$spec1){
   $this->result2="Начинаю создавать таблицу полученную из .sql файла... Ошибка!";
   $result->close();
   exit();
}else{
  unlink($this->uploadfile);
  $this->result2="Начинаю создавать таблицу полученную из .sql файла... Успешно!";
  $result->close();
}
    } else {
    $this->result1="Ошибка загрузки файла!";
}
}
}
$form = new wwsqlf;
```

Comment: Не работает, надо найти проблему - дебажим!!! Самый простой способ - через `die('smth');` чтобы найти где обрывается и `var_dump($var);` для поиска места где данные "обрываются"..
А так-то, надо бы поработать над архитектурой.. Зачем вам `$dir = $this->upploaddir` которые практически нигде не используются? Что вы в action записываете вообще? `action="<?php $form->uploadsql(); ?>"` насколько я вижу, тут вообще ничего не будет.. И так не делают. Это не ооп, это вы просто класс написали и пытаетесь его использовать.

Comment: В двух словах, на сколько я представляю реализацию вашей задачи: экшн =  `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`, потом после подключения класса, на этой же странице проверяете `if(isset($_FILES['userfile']))` и там уже создаёте экземпляр класса и вызываете функцию загрузки

Comment: Попробую реализовать как вы сказали.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Сделал так - экшн делает вывод на файл в котором идет require с бд и с классом.